# It is possible to install MongoDB on elementary OS?

Tags: release-juno

I have followed this tutorial https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ but I get,

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies: mongodb-org-server : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Is there any solution? Or what ubuntu version I need to install in order to install mongoDB?
My OS version when I run: `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 5.0 Juno
Release:    5.0
Codename:   juno
```

Thanks!

Comment: I went through the steps in that link, and everything went fine. Try running `sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoclean`. Next, run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`. Can you also add to your question the output of `curl --version`?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this, It should work, elementary OS Juno is based on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic, So follow the same reference:

Follow this order:

> wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo
>   apt-key add -
>
> echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu
>   bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse" | sudo tee
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

Comment: It works now.. THANKS! .but have another issue on elementary OS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59240381/mongotimeouterror-server-selection-timed-out-after-30000-ms Can you help, please?